# Disabling transaction button until the transaction is over in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a transaction button on my `asp.net` page.

If the user clicks on the *transaction* button, the button should be disabled until transaction is over.

*How can this be done using client scripting?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTransaction" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnTransaction_Click" OnClientClick="DisableMe(this.id);" />
```

Client Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableMe(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

And then on server side use

```
protected void btnTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // after your transction code executes
        btnTransaction.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Girija, I tried but once the button is disabled on client click it does not go on postback.

Comment: <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="BtnSubmit"  
        OnClientClick= "this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';  "   
        UseSubmitBehavior="false"    Text="Confirm Order" onclick="BtnSubmit_Click1" />

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, assuming that your transaction is an ajax request, you can do the following with javascript:

...

```
 performTransaction = function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('transaction_btn'), ajax;
    btn.disabled = true;

    // perform ajax request....
    ajax = ...;
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(ste) {
        btn.disabled = false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side script -
 
        OnClientClick= "this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';  enableImage();"
        UseSubmitBehavior="false"    Text="Confirm Order" onclick="BtnSubmit_Click1" />